# Views exposed block input filter width

Tags: theming, views

I'm trying to change the width of an input field in on a views exposed filter where the exposed filters are exposed as block, currently the default adds the width property set to 30 and I need to remove that so that it scales correctly in many parts of the site. I have tried the following function in my template file and it outputs the variables using dsm with the width property missing as I would expect it just doesn't render it properly.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_MYVIEW(&$vars, $hook) {
  if ($vars['form']['#id'] == 'MYVIEW') {     
    unset($vars['form']['MYFIELD']['#size']);
    dsm($vars);
  }
}
```

I don't want to use a css hack!

Comment: _I don't want to use a css hack!_ That isn't a hack, that's exactly what CSS is for...

Comment: I'll do that then